# How to pass in a variable to the click event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have the following function to delete a row.  I would like to reuse this function by passing in the `#search_result`.

```
function row_delete_ajax(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this row?'))) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";

        $.post(url, function(result){
            $('#search_result').empty();
            $('#search_result').append(result);
        });                
    }       
};
```

This is how I bind the function initially, But kind of stuck how to pass in `#search_result` to `row_delete_ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
    $('#search_result').find(".row_delete_ajax").click(row_delete_ajax);
}
```

Comment: This should help you - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it is to use the [[eventData]](http://api.jquery.com/click/) parameter:

> eventData: A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
    // Create an object with all the properties you want.
    var data = { id: '#search_result' }; 

    // Pass the data object as the first parameter in the click-event.
    $('#search_result').find(".row_delete_ajax").click(data, row_delete_ajax);
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
function row_delete_ajax(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this row?'))) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";

        $.post(url, function(result){
            $(event.data.id).empty();
            $(event.data.id).append(result);
        });                
    }       
};
```

Also check [event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) for example.

Comment: I like this way. Was actually wondering if there's a way we can access event parameter's properties. This is quite fun. FYI, I'm not the one who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about storing meta-information using data() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/?

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
    $('#search_result').find(".row_delete_ajax")
        .data('target', 'search_result')
        .click(row_delete_ajax);
}
```

Then your row_delete_ajax would look as follows:

```
function row_delete_ajax(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this row?'))) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";

        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('#' + target).load(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to rewrite your click slightly to be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
    $('#search_result').find(".row_delete_ajax").click(function (event) {
        row_delete_ajax(event, $("#search_result"));
    });
}
```

Then change your function to take both parameters:

```
function row_delete_ajax(event, searchResult) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this row?'))) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";

        $.post(url, function(result){
            searchResult.empty();
            searchResult.append(result);
        });                
    }       
};
```